# I can't find my github account in google search

Tags: github

I can't find my github account and repositories in google search. I wrote to support and here is an answer.

> Thank you for reaching out to GitHub Support. If you find that you are experiencing problems with your GitHub account not appearing in a Google search we would recommend reaching out to Google and submitting your Google profile page to be crawled. This can be done here.
>
> https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome

But google search console need to verify ownership.

Comment: I don't think that response makes much sense. How old is your account? Have you created any links to it anywhere, e.g. on your profile page here? If you link to it from an indexed page Google should find it.

Answer (score 3):

You need *public* repos, with commits in the master branch (which is indexed by Google, according to [`github.com/robots.txt`](https://github.com/robots.txt))

And if that fail, especially regarding your GitHub account URL, try and submit it to Google: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1